# How to Rename custom html color picker select text

Tags: html, css

When providing a default color it shows: `Other...`
How do I rename `Other...` to `Custom Color` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/4045/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't possible. The implementation of `<input type="color">` is up to the browser and you can't change it. You can, however, make your own color picker in HTML/CSS/JS.